# cache problem jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a fancybox, and for some reason it gets cached.
My current problem is layout this way.
I have main index page, where I have a link. Clicking
on the link open the jquery fancybox. The fancybox is
actually opening the page called data.php. That page has a drop down that
is populated through the database column. So when I change
something there, it updates the databased(I confirmed that)
it also changes the status on the index page (confirmed too)
but when I click the link and open the fancy box the drop down value is
still old value. If I logout and logback in then it works fine
or if I go to data.php page directly I can see the correct value. Which tells me
that something is wrong with the fancybox. I tried fancybox property cache: flase but
didnt help. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm still trying to parse the question, this is the strangest layout I've seen, it should't be, but damn that's hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is probably caching the data. You can have your data.php script tell the browser to not cache the data using HTTP headers.

An example:

```
<?php
    header('Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```